# IE Automatic Config Script (Proxy) blocking CSS Styles

Tags: css, proxy, styles, block

I am developing a Intranet website for a company and it appears perfectly in all browsers. However once it is on the network most of the frames all get shifted and the site becomes a jumbled messs.

I've confirmed the problem is with IE on the local network and the Automatic Configuration Script that IT has set in the LAN Settings.

My question is, how in the world can I find which CSS Style the Proxy/Script is blocking from running? What CSS style would IT possibly want to restrict?

Comment: F12 developer tools you can check what .css file is not working.

Comment: I see that did confirm the problem further. The script forces the site to be seen as a Intranet site. And the 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' option for IE is enabled.

Comment: So you can add to the code wich version of compatibility will be use?